# How to use the extended kalman filter for IMU and Optical Flow sensor fusion?

Tags: kalman-filter, opticalflow, sensor-fusion

I am building a quadcopter and i am using the pixhawk autopilot system with the px4flow sensor attached for optical flow data. The px4flow is a high speed smart camera (arm processor) with integrated gyro and height sensor, and it outputs linear velocities from the internal optical flow algorithm.

Now, i would like to improve on my position and velocity estimates by using an extended kalman filter to fuse the IMU and optical flow data.
I have already derived the state model function and the state transition matrix for the prediction step.

By problem lies within deriving a measurement model/function for the optical flow velocities, to be used in the update phase of the extended kalman filter. I believe i have to derive it from the optical flow algorithm some how, but that is as far as i have gotten.

*edit: Here is an article describing the px4flow unit and how it calculates the velocities. (forgot to add the link, now it's there)

https://pixhawk.org/_media/modules/px4flow_paper.pdf

Comment: If you want to show your work, you'll probably get better feedback.  To use EFK, you do need a measurement model that's based on your sensor.  I'm not sure that you provided enough information for someone to help in any detail on that.  To use EFK, you're also going to need Jacobians (first derivatives) of these functions, which could be challenging. An alternative might be to do unscented Kalman filter or some other derivative-free formulation - Before you get too far into a complicated model, you might want to think through your end game in that respect too.

Comment: I just added an article describing how the px4flow sensor calculates the velocities. I think that article has the answer for me, but I'm not able extrapolate it. I have designed EKF for IMU and GPS sensor fusion before, so i have a good understanding of how it works. I have also looked into the unscented kalman filter, but i still need the measurement function in order to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume (since you don't give any details) that state vector contains speed and position in world coordinates. Optical flow returns XY speed in body coordinates, so you have to rotate it according to yaw angle to get speed in world coordinates.

If this is your case, you can choose between:

- If state vector does not include orientation, pre-transform optical flow speed to world coordinates, and then use a linear observation model (zero matrix with ones in the position of X, Y speed in your state vector)
- If state vector includes orientation, you can write the full observation model that transform between world-body coordinates using angles.

That's basically the process. However, to get a better answer you should provide more details.